# While loop in test not breaking when condition is met

Tags: typescript

I am having an issue with a while loop I'm trying to use for an automated test I'm working on.

The section of the test the code relates to waits for an item to appear on a dashboard in WordPress - this can take 10-15 seconds usually. I've tried to implement a while loop to check for the presence of the expected item and if it's not there, increment the retries value by 1, refresh the page and check again.

However, even when the item appears on the dashboard, the loop continues to execute before eventually failing when the maximum number of attempts have been made.

Once the item appears on the dashboard I would expect the loop to break so it can move on to the next step in the test.

This is my code:

```
  async assertFFFItemIsOnDashboard(page: Page, subject: string) {
  const maxRetries = 15;
  let retries = 0;

  while (retries < maxRetries) {
    const rows = page.locator('a.row-title');
    const itemNames = await rows.evaluateAll((list) =>
      list.map((element) => element.ariaLabel)
    );

    if (itemNames.includes(`"${subject}" (Edit)`)) {
      break;
    }

    retries++;
    await waitFor(1000); 
    await page.reload().catch(e => undefined);
  }

  throw new Error(`Assertion did not pass after ${maxRetries} retries.`);
}
```

Comment: The error is thrown _outside_ the loop... Whether it ends because the element was found or the max retries were made, the error still gets thrown.

Comment: Maybe you want to replace `break` with `return`

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have replaced the break with a return and commented-out the 'throw new error' part. Interestingly, the loop still runs through the 15 attempts but then it does successfully move on to the next step and the test continues as expected. Ideally, I'd want the loop to break as soon as the element is located though - any suggestions for that please? Also, @jonrsharpe - I'm a little confused on where the error should go?